# How to make 'hg log --verbose' show files on multiple lines?

Tags: mercurial, windows-xp

By default all files changed in a changeset are on the same line, which makes them very easily to skip one or two, and hard to read.

How to make each file show on its own separate line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The real way to see information about changed *files* is to use `hg status`. This shows the files that were modified in revision 100:

```
$ hg status -c 100
```

But if you want to have the log messages as well, then `hg log` is of course a natural starting point. Unfortunately there is *no built-in switch* that will make it display one file per line.

However, the output of `hg log` is controlled by a [template system](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) and you can write your own styles for it. The default style is [here](http://selenic.com/hg/raw-file/tip/mercurial/templates/map-cmdline.default) and you can customize to do what you want by changing

```
file = ' {file}'
```

to

```
file = '{file}\n'
```

Then save the new style as `my-default.style` and add

```
[ui]
style = ~/path/to/my-default.style
```

to your configuration file. This gives you one file per line and it even works when there are spaces in your file names.

I'm aware of one problem: you lose colors in the `hg log` output. It turns out that Mercurial is cheating here! It doesn't actually use the default template I showed you when generating log output. It doesn't use any template system at all, it just generates the output using direct code since this is faster. The problem is that the color extension only work with the hard-coded template. When you switch to a custom template and thereby invoke the template engine, you lose the color output.

However, you can recover the colors by inserting the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) directly into your template (on Unix-like systems). Changing

```
changeset = 'changeset:   {rev}:{node|short}\n{branches}...
```

to

```
changeset = '\033[33mchangeset:   {rev}:{node|short}\033[0m\n{branches}...
```

does the trick and hard-codes a yellow header line for the changeset. Adjust the `changeset_verbose` and `changeset_quiet` lines as well and you'll have colored output with your own template.

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot get this to work. I've set the line style = "path to my file\my-style.default" and Hg just keeps saying "abort: style not found: "path to my file\my-style.default" ... ?! Do you have any idea perhaps?

Comment: Did you use double-quotes around the file name? As in `style = "the path"`? Surprisingly, config values are not quoted in the Mercurial config files, so it should be `style = the path`.

Comment: A-ah, you ment - no double quotes. Yes, my error ... it works now. I wasn't expecting that.

Comment: Martin, you're a treasure of information when it comes to Mercurial! :)

Answer (score 6):

The [hg template help](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates) file has this gem in its examples.

> Format lists, e.g. files:
>
> `$ hg log -r 0 --template "files:\n{files % ' {file}\n'}"`

This works on Windows without any translation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no built-in way to achieve this, but a bit of sed (also available for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) can help:

```
hg log --template "Rev: {rev}:{node}\nDate: {date|isodate}\nFiles: {files}\n\n" -l 10 | sed -e '/^Files:/s/ /\n  /g'
```

Output:

```
Rev: 1:2538bd4661c755ccab9b68e1d5e91144f6f97d33
Date: 2011-12-20 15:47 +0100
Files:
  test1.txt

Rev: 2:853a6f3c505308c9babff5a5a2f1e09303f1689c
Date: 2011-12-20 15:44 +0100
Files:
  test2.txt
  test3.txt
```

Explanation of `sed -e '/^Files:/s/ /\n  /g'`:

1. `/^Files:/` searches for lines starting woth "Files:", and applies the following search and replace just to those line
2. `s/ /\n  /g` replaces all lines with a newline, followed by the spaces.

This solution won't work when file names contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

To see all files that changed in a revision, use:

```
hg status --change REV
```

Answer (score 0):

- `hg log --style changelog`

OR

- `hg log --template "Description: {desc}\n"` - supported keywords like desc, files etc. are listed [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html)