# How to have hg log show commit timestamps in my timezone

Tags: mercurial

`hg log` by default shows the commit timestamp in the timezone it was committed in.  Is it possible to make it show the timestamp in a particular timezone?

Ideally a solution wouldn't require any external tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hg log --template "{date|localdate|rfc822date}\n"
```

So you take the date, convert it to local and format according to rfc822

Comment: If you want to modify the default styles to show the time in your local format, combine the above answer with that in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643612/how-to-make-hg-log-verbose-show-files-on-multiple-lines