# time for hg log --date

Tags: mercurial

I generate hg logs for some repositories (on the remote server where all local repos push their changes to) using this command:

```
hg log -R "path-to-repo" -b somebranch --date "$YESTERDAY to $TODAY"
```

where :

```
YESTERDAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "yesterday")
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

As an example this could be:

```
hg log -R "path-to-repo" -b somebranch --date "2012-11-27 to 2012-11-28"
```

But at what time: hour:minutes:seconds does the generated log start when specifying --date? End would be the time when the command is executed.

The reason I ask is that the log was empty when I ran the above at 10:00 but when I ran it 11:10 it found changes.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot about local timezone: date without TZ for mercurial is some predefined timezone (probably GMT)

BTW, "from yesterday" (without TZ-related headache) for hg log is static line `--date "-1"`

Example of log, when committer isn't from my local TZ

```
hg log --date "2012-11-04" --template "{date|date}\n"
Sat Nov 03 22:36:13 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 22:22:43 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:25:13 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:20:52 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:20:39 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:14:17 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:12:08 2012 -0400
Sat Nov 03 19:11:50 2012 -0400
```

Comment: Yes using --date "-1" gives the same result but at what time yesterday does that resolve to? It seems that the dates can be formatted using template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134624/how-to-have-hg-log-show-commit-timestamps-in-my-timezone Is it possible to pass hour/minutes/seconds to the --date option?

Comment: @u123 - just rewrite YESTERDAY and TODAY definition. It must have traling "00:00 NNNN", where NNNN is your local timezone or, from `hg help dates` example:  "Wed Dec 6 13:18:29 2006" (local timezone assumed)

Comment: Still don't get it. I have now tried: --date "2012-11-27 00:00 0400  to 2012-11-28 00:00 0400" No idea what my local timezone is

Comment: @u123 - at least +0400, `--template "{date|localdate|rfc822date}\n"` will show date (from log) in your local time with timezone

Comment: Seems to work now. I guess I don't need the timezone when all committers are in the same timezone? What if a user makes a commit eg. 2012-11-20 but first pushes it the 2012-11-25 will it appear in the log as the commit timestamp or the push timestamp?

Comment: @u123 - AFAIK, commit timestamp used (because it's part of SHA1, which must not be changed on publishing)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20311/discussion-between-u123-and-lazy-badger)