# hg log: Differing behavior between {files} template in direct call and embedded in --verbose

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality as [How to make 'hg log --verbose' show files on multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643612/how-to-make-hg-log-verbose-show-files-on-multiple-lines) 
and I've more or less achieved my goal. But I don't understand what's different in my calling `{files}` as an argument to `hg log --template` and using `{files}` as a keyword inside the .style file I've created. Although I'd expect them to have the same behavior, they don't.

Here's what I've done (as directed by [the answer to the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8643761/2462008)):

1. Downloaded and modified my own `my-default.style` file. For this exercise I've reduced the contents of the file to this:

   ```
   changeset_verbose = '{files}\n'
   file = '{file}\n'
   ```
2. Linked to that style file in an hg config file.

If I call `hg log -r1 -v` I get the proper, newline-separated output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
```

But if I call `hg log -r1 --template {files}` I get the default, space-separated output:

```
file1.txt file2.txt ...
```

By hacking `changeset_verbose` as I've done I can work around this problem. But ideally I'd like to reference my style file within command-line templates. So: where is the behavior for the `{files}` that I call from the command line defined? And how I can override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to reference a style file using a `--style` parameter.  Alternatively, you can do it all on the command line with something like this:

```
hg log -r 1 --template "{files % '{file}\n'}"
```

Type

```
hg help template
```

for more examples and explanation.